Quarter over Quarter for monthly spend with Pandas
I have some transaction data that after grouping by date and FacilityID that looks like the below after the grouping. I'm trying to calculate the quarter over quarter change for all of the transactions, so the sum of the total spend of all of the Facilities combined (i.e. the aggregate spend in all 3 months of both the current quarter and the 3 months of the prior year quarter). So in this example, I would just want the sum of spend for Facility #1, for April-June 2024 over Facility #1 April-June 2023 sum of total spend to get the change. Facility 2 should be excluded because it doesn't have any spend in April of 2023 or 2024.
If there were other facilities that had data for April-June 2024 and April-June 2023 (e.g. Facility 7 and 9) then I would want the total spend for the quarter for Facility 1,7, and 9 combined, over the previous quarter. I just need the most recent quarter, which depending on the month, may only have 1-2 months of data, which is fine.

This is the code I've tried so far, but it's including Facility 2 in the code as well, when it should be excluded since it doesn't have any data in April 2024 and 2023.
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def open_file(path, quarter_number, months):
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame({'Date':["2024-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01", "2024-06-01","2024-05-01","2023-04-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01", "2023-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01"],
                         'FacilityID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4],
                         'TotalSpend': [100,110,120,50,70,90,100,110,150,140,120,60,90,190,150]
    }).set_index('Date')
    df = df_raw.groupby(['Date', 'FacilityID'])['TotalSpend'].sum()
    print(df)

    cur_dates = []
    prev_dates = []

    for month in months:
        cur_date = datetime.date(2024, month, 1)
        prev_date = datetime.date(cur_date.year - 1, month, 1)
        cur_dates.append(cur_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        prev_dates.append(prev_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    cur_quarter_data = pd.concat(
        [df.loc[date] if date in df.index.levels[0] else pd.Series(dtype='float64') for date in cur_dates])

    prev_quarter_data = pd.concat(
        [df.loc[date] if date in df.index.levels[0] else pd.Series(dtype='float64') for date in prev_dates])

    common_facilities = cur_quarter_data.index.intersection(prev_quarter_data.index)


    cur_quarter_vals = cur_quarter_data.loc[common_facilities]
    prev_quarter_vals = prev_quarter_data.loc[common_facilities]

    yoy_change = (cur_quarter_vals.sum() - prev_quarter_vals.sum()) / prev_quarter_vals.sum() * 100
    return yoy_change

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change = open_file("path",2 ,[4,5,6])
    print(change)


Example Code
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':["2024-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01", "2024-06-01","2024-05-01","2023-04-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01", "2023-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01"], 'FacilityID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4], 'TotalSpend': [100,110,120,50,70,90,100,110,150,140,120,60,90,190,150]})

df
          Date  FacilityID  TotalSpend
0   2024-04-01           1         100
1   2024-05-01           1         110
2   2024-06-01           1         120
3   2024-06-01           1          50  <-- duplicated date
4   2024-05-01           1          70  <-- duplicated date
5   2023-04-01           1          90
6   2023-05-01           1         100
7   2023-06-01           1         110
8   2024-05-01           2         150
9   2024-06-01           2         140
10  2023-05-01           2         120
11  2023-06-01           2          60
12  2023-04-01           3          90
13  2024-05-01           4         190
14  2024-06-01           4         150

Your sample has a duplicated month date in same ID. I assume this is your intention, and I'll proceed by combining them to get the result.
Code
# convert 'Date' column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# groupby & resample 2times (sum duplicate month & agg by quarter)
tmp = (df.groupby('FacilityID')
         .resample('MS', on='Date')['TotalSpend']
         .sum(min_count=1)
         .reset_index()
         .groupby('FacilityID')
         .resample('QS', on='Date')['TotalSpend']
         .agg(['sum', 'count'])
)

# make prev data using shift index by 12 months
tmp_prev = (tmp1.reset_index(level=0)
                .shift(freq='12MS')
                .reset_index()
)

# merge current and previous periods data, keep only rows both count == 3
out = tmp.merge(
    tmp_prev, on=['Date', 'FacilityID'], how='left', suffixes=['_cur', '_prev']
)[lambda x: x.pop('count_cur').eq(3) & x.pop('count_prev').eq(3)]

out:
        Date  FacilityID  sum_cur  sum_prev
4 2024-04-01           1    450.0     300.0

Whether you're looking for the difference between sum_cur and sum_prev or a ratio, you should be able to get the result you want.

Yes, the duplicate data was intentional as there could be multiple transactions by a facility in a month. Thanks!

Does this aggregate all of the values? I was trying to get the aggregate quarter over quarter change, not by specific facility, but the aggregate for the quarter

@user3628240 For each ID, if you have all three months of data for the current quarter and all three months of data for the corresponding quarter in the previous year, you sum the quarter and the corresponding quarter in the previous year. In the case of ID 1, it have 3 months of data from 2023Q2 and all 3 months of data from 2024Q2, so this is the result. For IDs 2, 3, 4, there is no such case.

Oh ok, and then I can just sum up all of the facilities that fit the criteria with 3 months of data in the current and previous year.
